# Is user visiting 'Home screen webpage' or on safari

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile, safari

Is there is way to know in JavaScript, if the user has loaded the website from homescreen  after doing add to home screen or is he browsing normally via safari .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari has a way...

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {
    // From home screen

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.referrer` to see where the user came from. But only if the user allows submit of referrer in his browser.

When the URL comes from a bookmark (supposed that home screen is the same as bookmark) the referrer is empty. So this would be a hint, not more.

Other than that there is no way to see where the user came from.

Comment: if the user typed my url in browser then too referrer is not available